# using Ajax to send information to classic ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I have a reset button on my html table. When it's clicked, it gets information related to its row, particularly the 'record ID' and 'Active'. I'm trying to take the record Id number and send it to my asp page called resetinbound.asp

This is my first time using AJAX so I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct but here is the code for the On Click:

```
 $(function(){
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var RecID = tr.find('.RecID').text();
    var active = tr.find('.active').text();
    alert('id: '+RecID+', Active: ' + active);

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
             url: "resetInbound.asp",
             data: RecID,
             success: function() { 
                alert("I am back after sending data sucessfully to server.");}
             });
      // Ajax call ends  



});
});
```

The ASP file code:

```
Dim RecID
RecID = Request.QueryString("RecID")
```

I also tried Request.Form and Request.BinaryRead but none of them worked. It seems like the code doesn't even reach the ASP page at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, your AJAX call is `POST`ing the data, so you should be receiving it in your ASP page via `Request.Form()`.

Comment: @Bond Thank you, I have changed it to Request.Form() but im still not getting the information to my ASP page.

Comment: Does resetInbound.asp work if it's called traditionally, i.e. without AJAX? Make a test page with a form on it, set its action to "resetInbound.asp", add your RecID field (type of field doesn't really matter), and add a submit button. Do you see what you expect to see?

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me what's supposed to happen on the calling page if the AJAX call is successful: you're not retrieving any data from the asp page, so how is your calling code supposed to figure out whether anything happened?

Comment: @Martha The ASP file uses the RecID field to enter my database and alter some information there.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` member of your AJAX param needs to be an object that specifies the name and value of each parameter. So you'll need to change this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "resetInbound.asp",
    data: RecID,
    ...
});
```

To:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "resetInbound.asp",
    data: { "RecID": RecID },
    ...
});
```

And then you should receive a named parameter in your ASP page:

```vb
strID = Request.Form("RecID")
```

---

If you want to make things easier to debug, however, use `GET` instead of `POST` and pass your values via querystring/URL:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "resetInbound.asp?recID=" + RecID,
    ...
});
```

Then receive the param via `Request.QueryString()`:

```vb
strID = Request.QueryString("recID")
```

Comment: Thank you for this amazing clarification. Upon debugging, it seems that my problem is with the form in my html page, since the information is still not going to my ASP page. The reset buttons on my table get looped (one reset button per row) for X amount of rows. So do I still need a form or does AJAX replace the need for forms?

Comment: Are you seeing the proper values in your `alert()` function? I just assumed that was working but the following AJAX call wasn't.

Comment: yes the alert function provides the RecID and Active status. The Ajax call after isnt taking the information

Comment: If you're getting the proper values in your `alert()`, let's just try this. Before your AJAX call, add this line: `window.location.href = "resetInbound.asp?recID=" + RecID;`. That will just redirect you to your ASP page so you can see exactly how it's being called with the querystring param.

Comment: adding this line disabled the alert, so I no longer see the alert box when I click the button, and it doesnt redirect me to the ASP page. 

I did change it to window.location.href = "resetInbound.asp?recID=" + RecID; Since my asp file is in the same location but I get the same problem

Comment: upon more debugging...the window line now works and it sends to the ASP page, the problem was data: { "RecID": RecID }, I had to change that to data: {RecID},

Comment: The post sends successfully, the alert for success runs after. The problem is I do a response.write for the Rec ID on the ASP page and it is NULL.. I am using post and my ASP code to get it is RecID= Request.Form("RecID") as you stated above.

what do you think is the issue?


EDIT: Your window line is what gets the AJAX going...it gets both alerts and then goes to the ASP page; which is very weird.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage the use of `GET` in these instances but that is just my opinion, answers still good.